# [Python]: How to update python property in a good way

Tags: python, python-class

I'm new to Python and I'm working on a crawler project.

I have a case want to ask you about good way to handle.
For example.

```
class Student:
  def __init__(
    self, 
    user_id: str,
    name: str = None, 
    age: int = None, 
    gender: str = None
  ):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender

user_id = "test_user_id"

# after crawling data by selenium/scrapy
# we have 2 types to build/update class property

# STYLE 1:
student = Student(user_id)

student.name = "AAAA"
student.age = "18"
student.gender = "male"


# STYLE 2:
name = "AAAA"
age = "18"
gender = "male"

student = Student(
  user_id=user_id, 
  name=name, 
  age=age, 
  gender=gender)
```

About the **#STYLE 1**, I'm not really it's a good way or not. But about #STYLE 2 I think it's gonna have some problem because we have to define a lot of variables (hard to debug), and we have to guarantee the variables have to be initialized before create class instance.

That's my question, please give me your guys idea about this or which way do you guy prefer.

Comment: no need to initialize you can directly pass them as Student(user_id="AAAA" ....).
If there are a lot of variables we generally tend to create a dataclass and then pass values from dataclass to your instance initialization. this will help you keep track of variables and avoid errors

Comment: You should do `from typing import Optional` and change the typing in `__init__` to `name: Optional[str] = None` if they are intended to be truly optional.

By considering whether or not they are actually optional you can further explore which pattern is best for your use case.

Comment: @Punit 
Thank you guys comment, I got your guys point. So eventually which parttern do you guys prefer? Or do we have any criteria to judge? Props and cons maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this question will be closed soon as it requires opinion based answers, and is probably out of scope here. Nevertheless it raises an interesting point, so I will give my two cents.

If you are talking about properties that you will set at once, on creation or immediately after, I would definitely go with the second approach. As Punit said in a comment, you can (and usually will) directly pass the values, without creating intermediate variables unless they are already there. And if some of the properties are really necessary to work with the instance, I would avoid specifying a default value, thus making them required.

This way the instance creation is IMO both more readable and more reliable. And if you have really many arguments, you can require that most or all are passed as kwargs, which will further improve readability.

Then you may sometimes have other properties which are not needed, or may be even unknown, at creation time - and of course those will be set later, with the first style.

Answer (score 0):

---

The best to go about this is to have all this code compressed into a smaller block. This helps make the code look more concise. Also, you forgot to set user_id in STYLE #1.

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, id: int, name: str, age: int, gender: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender


data = [] #scraped data from target site

# assuming a user instance looks like this: { name, age, id, gender }
# using list comprehensions to make it look cool
# you can replace the arguments in `Student()` with whatever fits the 
# response from target site
users = [Student(i.id, i.name, i.age, i.gender) for i in data]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would distinguish 2 cases here: Creation of the instance and update.

In the first case you can directly assign the values to the constructor of the class.

```py
classStudent:
   def __init__(self, user_id: str, name: str = None, age: int = None, gender: str = None):
     self.user_id = user_id # You forgot this attribute!
     self.name = name
     self.age = age
     self.gender = gender
```

```py
student = Student(
     # All the values you have available like you do in STYLE 2
)
```

In the case of updating it would be easier without using the variables and assigning them directly. Hard to debug, as you said.

```py
student.name = "YYYY"
student.age = "18"
student.gender = "male"
```

There is nothing wrong in doing this in Python as you don't have to make getters and setters like other languages.

Even so, it would be recommended that you add conditionals to check if the values are valid before making the modification.